# How can I receive data with WCF nettcpbinding when my database result is very great?

Tags: wcf, nettcpbinding, maxreceivedmessagesize

does exist any way to receive data in multy step 
or other protocol that i use it that support the data greater than Int.MaxValue
because nettcpBinding only support data less than Int.MaxValue
with this attribute:

```
maxReceivedMessageSize = "2147483647"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think for your scenario, the better way will be to use [chunking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717050.aspx) (see also [WCF Chunking / Streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323585/wcf-chunking-streaming)) or [streaming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx), and not trying to pass all the data in one time.